# powerapps connection to retrieve information in the powerapps canvas form a onedrive word file

Tags: onedrive, powerapps, power-automate, cpu-word

ok, so
i've created an powerapps canvas which generates a onedrive word file in a certain folder etc. the input is given in powerapps canvas. now i want to know if its possible to make a certain button in powerapps which is connected to a textbox. that if you fill in the correct word file name it will return the information thats is generated in de word file to the canvas file.

so you can add more info etcetc in that way you can edit some information en save it again

i've tried to find the solution but no one seems to have done this

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be using a Power Automate flow triggered from Power Apps. If you use the Power Apps trigger V2, you can respond to the application. In the flow you can use the OneDrive connector to get the file contents and return it back to the app.